# Want to print only files of a specific type

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

In Command Prompt, I type the following and it recursively pipes all folders/sub-folders into a `.txt` file which I can then open in Excel:

```
dir /s folder > c:\filelist.txt
```

Is there any way I can make this only print `.html`, `.htm`, `.doc` and `.pdf` files?

Comment: `dir /s /b *.htm *.doc *.pdf >c:\filelist.txt`

Comment: @Stephan This prints out all gifs and images also, it seems?

Comment: why should it? (it doesn't on my computer)

Comment: @Stephan It is in my case - within sub-folders, it is finding .gif files and printing them. Any idea why this may be so?

Comment: A space after one of the `*` could be a reason.

Comment: See [Dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) Help for more tips. Stephan's code works for me.